# parámetros sin usar en constructor python

Tags: python, funciones, constructor, parametros, self

Tengo una clase llamada 'mibd' y en ella tengo 2 funciones, una de ellas es el constructor de mi clase.Algo así:

```
class mibd():
 def __init__(self,nombre,apellido)
       self.nombre=nombre
       self.apellido=apellido
 
 def mostrarmensaje():
       mostrar="Hola mundo"
       return mostrar
```

Desde otra clase para llamar mi metodo mostrarmensaje(), hago lo siguiente.

```
from basededatos import bd as realiza
objeto=realiza("Juan","López")
objeto.mostrarmensaje()
```

Ahora mi duda quizás es muy tonta, pero si ejecuto eso me marca error, yo quisiera saber si no usar los parámetros de mi constructor genera el problema, es decir si yo declaro un constructor **forzosamente** debo hacer uso de sus parametros?. Hice prueba usandolos en la función mostrarmensaje y ya no me da error, algo así:

```
def mostrarmensaje(self):
    mostrar=f"Hola {self.nombre} {self.apellido}"
    return mostrar
```

Quizás es algo muy básico pero me está dando vueltas en la cabeza. Espero puedan ayudarme. Desde ya muchas gracias :D

Comment: El problema es que todos los metodos de un objeto deben declarar como primer parámetro `self`, tanto si lo van a usar como si no. Por otro lado, si no usan `self` cabe preguntarse por qué implementarlos como métodos de un objeto ¿no serían más bien una función "normal"? Si quieres que sean un método de una clase por motivos de organizar el código, pero no necesitan acceder a atributos del objeto (y por tanto no necesitan self) puedes declararlos como metodos estáticos, poniendo delante el decorador `@staticmethod`

Comment: Otro detalle, es practica habitual (de hecho un convenio) que los nombres de clase comiencen por mayúscula.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu respuesta, creo que entiendo tu punto.Bueno, en este caso estoy practicando con el import de clases, como dices para organizarlos. Realmente voy iniciando en esto de manera autodidacta, sabes dónde podría ver la documentación que respecta a ese tipo de reglas como la de usar mayúscula en las clases?.

Comment: @abulafia merece una respuesta?

Comment: Lo siento, no fue mi intención hacerles perder tiempo, seguiré buscando por mi cuenta. Y de nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda, la verdad me quedó bien claro, estaba bloqueado. Excelente noche.

Comment: NovatoPython88 Quizás has malintepretado el comentario de @gbianchi. No quiso decir si tu pregunta merecería una respuesta, sino más bien si mi comentario merecería ser expandido en forma de respuesta, para poder explicarme mejor. Creo que sí, y así lo he hecho.

Answer (score 0):

El problema con tu primer ejemplo es que has declarado un método (`mostrarmensaje`) sin parámetros, pero todos los métodos de un objeto deben declarar obligatoriamente un primer parámetro a través del cual recibirán el objeto sobre el que deben operar. Este primer parámetro típicamente se llama `self` (por convenio, no porque tenga ningún significado especial para el lenguaje).

Cuando en tu programa escribes `objeto.mostrarmensaje()` lo que hace Python en realidad es `mibd.mostrarmensaje(objeto)` (siendo `midb` la clase).

Al no haber declarado un parámetro para ese método, la llamada falla. La solución es tan simple como añadirle el parámetro `self` a tu método aunque no lo uses.

Por otro lado, si un método no usa `self` cabe preguntarse por qué implementarlo como método de un objeto ¿no serían más bien una función "normal", ya que están completamente desligadas del objeto? De hecho esto es lo recomendado en general, implementarlo como una función aparte fuera del objeto. Esa función la podrías importar y usar por ejemplo así:

```
from basedatos import mostrarmensaje

mostrarmensaje()
```

Si, por motivos de organizar el código, quieres que sea un método de una clase pero no necesita acceder a atributos del objeto (y por tanto no necesita el `self`) puedes invocarlo a través del nombre de la clase, en lugar de instanciar un objeto:

```
from basedatos import midb

midb.mostrarmensaje()
```

Finalmente, también puedes añadirle a ese método el decorador `@staticmethod`, así:

```
class mibd():
 def __init__(self,nombre,apellido)
       self.nombre=nombre
       self.apellido=apellido

 @staticmethod
 def mostrarmensaje():
       mostrar="Hola mundo"
       return mostrar
```

Esto te da la opción de ejecutarlo directamente desde la clase, como en el ejemplo anterior, es decir, `midb.mostrarmensaje()`, pero también te permite instanciarlo en un objeto y ejecutarlo desde el objeto, con `objeto.mostrarmensaje()`.

Al estar marcado como `@staticmethod` Python no intentará pasarle como parámetro el objeto, aunque lo invoques a través de él.

**Nota extra**. Es costumbre en el mundo Python usar para las clases nombres en mayúscula y en `CamelCase`, y para las funciones y resto de variables nombres en minúscula y `snake_case`.

Para más detalles sobre lo que se considera buen estilo en el código fuente puedes leer el [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: MIL GRACIAS!, está muy claro y súper explicado.

Comment: De nada! Si la respuesta ha resuelto la duda puedes marcarla como aceptada.